# Strings and substrings

Tags: c, string, substring

I tried to work with different versions but all of them do not work unfortunetaly. That is why I am posting here. I need to return an array of two strings. The first is substring from the beginning up to but not including the comma. The second is the substring of s after the comma. String contains only one comma.  Also I need to use char * strchr(const char *s, int c).  Well, it did not help me. Please, help mw with this, spent many of hours......thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   char **split_on_comma(const char * s){




   //this piece of code does not work
   /*int i;
   char array[80];

    for (i=0; i<strlen(s)-1; i++){
       if(substr=(s[i],',')==NULL){
        array[i]=s[i];
      } else
  }*/

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please describe what you expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: Hint `strchr(), *p = '\0'; strdup()`.

Comment: People who are working on the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551355/splitting-a-string-at-a-delimiter-and-storing-substrings-in-char-array-in-c

Answer (score 2):

This is quite trivial: just copy both halves of the string.

```
char **split_on_comma(const char *str)
{
    const char *p = strchr(str, ',');
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char **subs = malloc(2 * sizeof subs[0]);
    ptrdiff_t len1 = p - str;
    ptrdiff_t len2 = str + strlen(str) - (p + 1);

    // copy and 0-terminate first half
    subs[0] = malloc(len1 + 1);
    memcpy(subs[0], str, len1);
    subs[0][len1] = 0;

    // copy and 0-terminate second half
    subs[1] = malloc(len2 + 1);
    memcpy(subs[1], p + 1, len2);
    subs[1][len2] = 0;

    return subs;
}
```

Checks against `malloc()` returning `NULL` are omitted for clarity, shall be included in production code though.

Comment: @Manuel what is Google? (and what are all those extraneous question marks? I'm not deaf!)